# what is the meaning of -Infinity (minus Infinity)

Tags: javascript

In this code:

```js
function max(...numbers){
  let result = -Infinity; // <= here's the question
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (number > result) result = number
  }
  return result;
}
```

I don't understand the meaning of the minus in front of infinity. The code returns the highest number given in the arguments. I returns `Infinity` without the minus.

Comment: To initiate the variable with the lowest possible value so that the `if` condition always will be true the first time

Comment: The minus makes it “negative infinity” if that’s what you’re asking, just as -4 is negative four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Infinity` is the highest possible number. It also affects math like this:

```js
let x = 1.797693134862315E+308; // highest possible number
console.log(x * 1.1);

let y = Infinity;

console.log(15 + y);
console.log(y - 1000000);
console.log(y / 0);
console.log(0 / y);
console.log(1 / y);
```

`-Infinity` is the same, but negative.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's meant to be the lowest possible number, just like how Infinity is the highest possible number.

Since `-Infinity` is less than other non-infinity numbers, it can be used as the bottom of a max-number finding equation.

See these two examples of what happens with Infinity vs negative Infinity:

```js
function max(...numbers){
  let result = -Infinity; // <= Negative
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (number > result) result = number
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(max(5, 38, 71, 57))
```

```js
function max(...numbers){
  let result = Infinity; // <= Positive (now the highest number)
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (number > result) result = number
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(max(5, 38, 71, 57))
```

Do note that -Infinity and Infinity still *have* a sign, so if you multiply `-Infinity` and `-5`, it will result in `Infinity`.